# Two different pages that share the same content?

Tags: pages, content, sharing

I have a self-hosted WordPress site. I need to display the same content on two different pages (a contact page and another page used for promotion purposes).

They will need to have minor tweaks such as a different heading for the H1 and show two different form fields based on the page.

I've used the Advanced Custom Fields plug-in to make it easier for content editors to modify the pages, but I cannot figure out how to just have one place they can go to edit the form fields, sub-text, images, etc. and display this info in two different pages.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you take a look at Options Page Add-on for Advanced Custom Field?
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

I created an option page for my client once where they enter promotion content once in that options page, and display that same information elsewhere via widget, shortcode, and PHP functions.

It costs 25AUD but it's unlimited license and is well worth the price. I bought all of their Add-ons and it saved me a lot of time making client friendly stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates). I think you'll get what you want by creating a template that both pages will share.

EDIT: sorry I missed page have to display two different form. Well there are multiple ways to do that. For example :

same template and use of [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/shortcode_api)s to add forms or two different templates or same template and use of conditional tags such as [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/is_page)

Comment: Thanks. I've got the shared template part down, I'm just not sure how to make it so they can go into the WP Admin and enter/modify the info one time and have it show up on both pages? (/my-promotion and /contact)

Comment: OK, maybe a mini-plugin that will add the custom field and users will set it in an option page. Then you will grab custom field values and echo in pages my-promotion and contact